# Will a scroll event also fire if the targeting element does not exist?

Tags: jquery, performance, events, scroll

I have a sidebar as subnavigation and attached some custom javascript to highlight the navlinks inside of it during the user scrolls down the sections. I included this javascript into my main js file. The sidebar is not included on every page. For performance I'd like to know, if the attached scroll event to this sidebar also fires on a site where the sidebar is not included or is this piece of script ignored on these sites?

```
        // waypoint for fixed sidebar
        $('.tg-desktop__accordionWrapper').waypoint(function (direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                $(this.element).addClass('tg-accordion__sidebar--fixed');
            } else {
                $(this.element).removeClass('tg-accordion__sidebar--fixed');
            }
        });

        // cache the navigation links 
        var $navigationLinks = $('.tg-accordion__sidebarLink');
        // cache (in reversed order) the sections
        var $sections = $($(".tg-accordion__text").get().reverse());

        // map each section id to their corresponding navigation link
        var sectionIdTonavigationLink = {};
        $sections.each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = $('.tg-accordion__sidebarLink[href=#' + id + ']');
        });

        // throttle function, enforces a minimum time interval
        function throttle(fn, interval) {
            var lastCall, timeoutId;
            return function () {
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                if (lastCall && now < (lastCall + interval) ) {
                    // if we are inside the interval we wait
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                        lastCall = now;
                        fn.call();
                    }, interval - (now - lastCall) );
                } else {
                    // otherwise, we directly call the function 
                    lastCall = now;
                    fn.call();
                }
            };
        }

        function highlightNavigation() {
            // get the current vertical position of the scroll bar
            var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

            // iterate the sections
            $sections.each(function() {
                var currentSection = $(this);
                // get the position of the section
                var sectionTop = currentSection.offset().top;

                // if the user has scrolled over the top of the section  
                if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
                    // get the section id
                    var id = currentSection.attr('id');
                    // get the corresponding navigation link
                    var $navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
                    // if the link is not active
                    if (!$navigationLink.hasClass('active')) {
                        // remove .active class from all the links
                        $navigationLinks.removeClass('active');
                        // add .active class to the current link
                        $navigationLink.addClass('active');
                    }
                    // we have found our section, so we return false to exit the each loop
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        $(window).scroll( throttle(highlightNavigation,100) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, a scroll handler is attached unconditionally, therefore yes, that handler will fire even in the absense of a sidebar. And, in all probability, due to the tollerant nature of jQuery, nothing will throw; but without a sidebar, none of the desired side-effects will happen.

It should be very simple not to attach a scroll handler when no sidebar is present. In fact it would appear that none of the code in the question is necessary on such pages (or "sites" if you like).

Something like this, I expect :

```
var $navigationLinks = $('.tg-accordion__sidebarLink');

if( $navigationLinks.length > 0 ) {
    $('.tg-desktop__accordionWrapper').waypoint(function(direction) {
        ...
    });

    ...
    ...
    ...

    function throttle(fn, interval) {
        ...
    }

    function highlightNavigation() {
        ...
    }

    $(window).scroll( throttle(highlightNavigation, 100) );
}
```

Of course, if you had a Single Page Application (SPA), and some content had a sidebar and some didn't, then this approach wouldn't work. You could leave the scroll handler permanently attached (doing nada in some cases), or you could arrange for the scroll handler to be attached/detached in sympathy with the content.

Comment: thanks! made my day, did not think about the length option for the function! I guess this should always be done, if scroll or resize handlers are only for occasionally use :-) Merry Christmas @Roamer-1888